# Limit size of .xsession-error

Tags: linux, logging, command-line-interface

how to limit size of .xsession-error to certain size, say 10 MB instead of deleting it every time or preventing its creation altogether?

there are solutions offered around internet with the strategies to delete or prevent but I guess it would be wiser to keep it and only limit it. who knows, error logs could/should be useful after all.

Comment: `tail -c 10M .xsession-error > .xsession-error` in a crontab ?

Comment: it doesn't work as I tested it directly on CLI manually (that is without scheduling in crontab). the output is 0 size file.